# how to get state machine current state from code activity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, state-machine-workflow

I need some help in how I can get the current state of my state machine so that I can return it as part of a Receive Send Reply Activity

So I have a WCF method that triggers a state public string GetResults(int id) I want in the workflow to get the current state and return as a string

I have looked [here](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tracking%20states%20with%20WorkflowServices&referringTitle=How%20do%20I%20get%20the%20current%20state%20and%20possible%20transitions%20of%20a%20State%20Machine%3F) and this allows the States to be logged to the output but how do I access this through code.

Thanks